# How to check a null value with an extension method using Object.prototype

Tags: javascript

There are a variety of places where I need to check if a JavaScript variable is null or empty string so I wrote an extension method that looks like this:

```
Object.prototype.IsNullOrEmptyString = function()
{
    return (this == null || (typeof this === "string" && this.length == 0));
}
```

I then call it like so:

```
var someVariable = null;

if (someVariable.IsNullOrEmptyString())
    alert("do something");
```

But that doesn't work because, at the point of evaluation in the if statement, someVariable is null.  The error I keep getting is "someVariable is null".

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/AhnkF/  (run in Firefox and notice the error console)

Is there anyway to do what I want and have a single extension method check for null and other things at the same time?

Comment: Extending Object is not a good idea. It should be considered "final"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` does not have any properties or methods. You have to create a function, and pass the variable, so it can be tested. Note: To test whether a variable is really an empty string, using `=== ""` is recommended.<sup>*</sup>

```
function isNullOrEmpty(test) {
    return test === null || test === "";
}

var someVariable = null;
if (isNullOrEmpty(someVariable)) alert("Do something");
```

<sup>*</sup> about `==` and `===`. The following comparisons are `true`:

```
null == undefined
"" == 0;
"" == false
"" ==
```

Comment: I had a global helper function that did that.  I was just hoping to use an extension method instead.  Oh well.

Comment: @sohtimsso1970 I refer back to my first sentence: `null does not have any properties or methods`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your variable is not an object, so its not working. Do it this way.

```
Object.prototype.IsNullOrEmptyString = function(obj)
{
    return (obj == null || (typeof this === "string" && this.length == 0));
}


if(Object.IsNullOrEmptyString(null))
  alert('yes');
```

Comment: You probably want to set it on `Object`, not on `Object.prototype` (or `Object.IsNullOrEmptyString` won’t exist).

Comment: lol sidicious, in order to extend Object you need to use prototype

Comment: @SenadMeškin, `Object.IsNullOrEmptyString` works because when you extend `Object.prototype` you extend every and all objects, including function objects, as the `Object` constructor, which is not desirable at all in this case e.g. `Function.IsNullOrEmpty`, `({}).IsNullOrEmpty`, `document.IsNullOrEmpty`, etc., will be extended. As @Sidnicious suggest, if you want to use your function on `Object`, just create a property on it (`Object.isNullOrEmpty = function() { /*...*/ };`)

Comment: You definitely want to set the method on just `Object`, not `Object.prototype`, since you don't want every object to have the method. It would even show up in `for-in` loops performed on every Object instance and it could do a big damage.

Answer (score 1):

just make it a function call.

```
function IsEmptyString(value)
{
    return (value == null ||
            value === "");
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/VS84L/)

Edit: consolidated (=== undefined and === null) into (== null)

Comment: +1 for including undefined.  Hadn't thought of that, but I need to be checking for that too in this scenario.

Comment: For shortness, checking `value === undefined || value === null` is completely equivalent to checking `value == null` (with the non strict equals operator), this form implicitly checks for `null` or `undefined`, with the added bonus on not relying on the `window.undefined` property, because `undefined` is  *not* a keyword such as `null`, and on ES3 implementations, it's value could be overwritten.

Comment: @sohtimsso1970 Test for `typeof test == "undefined"` instead of `test === undefined`. `undefined` can be overwritten by an arbitrary value.